# went away, singing the national anthem?

Tags: present-participles

Can "singing a song" be moved to the front in the following?

> 1. The students went away, singing the national anthem.
> 2. Singing a song, the students went away.

What about the following?

> 3. The dog lay dozing in front of the door.
> 4. Dozing in front of the door, the dog lay.
> 5. Jess came flying round the corner.
> 6. Flying round the corner, Jess came.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: 1) is not the same punctuation as  3) and 5).

Answer (score 2):

Placing the participle clause at the head of the sentence is grammatical but is a characteristic of storytelling not everyday speech. There has to be a reason to depart from the usual ordering, since all departures are unnatural to some degree.

Your main clauses are especially "light", so I'm just taking them as quick-and-dirty examples, no more. We'd normally expect a heavier clause there:

> Flying round the corner, Jess came screaming at the top of his lungs, "It's a female grizzly bear with cubs!"
>
> Dozing in front of the door, the dog lay on its side.